# ISC-DHCPd how to assign different DHCP settings even if request originated from different subnet?

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcp

### Network setup

- 10.0.1.0/28 (VLAN 1)
- 10.0.1.32/28 (VLAN 1)

### ISC-DHCPd setup

```
subnet 10.0.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.240 {
  option routers 10.0.1.1;
}

subnet 10.0.1.32 netmask 255.255.255.240 {
  option routers 10.0.1.33;
}

host {
  fixed-address 10.0.1.34;
  hardware ethernet 00:11:22:33:44:55:66;
}
```

The networks are using a DHCP relay, that can only be configured on a per-VLAN basis.

The source of the relayed/proxied DHCPDISCOVER will, in both cases, be the router of the first subnet.
Therefore ISC-DHCPd sends no DHCPOFFER and logs "no free leases" for any host that has a statically configured IP of the second subnet (10.0.1.32/28).

### dhcpd.conf manual states

> When dhcpd tries to find a host declaration  for  a  client,  it 
>   first looks for a host declaration which has a fixed-address
>   declaration that lists an IP address **that is valid for the subnet
>   or shared  network  on which  the client  is booting**.

### Question

How can I configure the ISC-DHCPd in a way that it will accept relayed requests for all subnets, and assign a lease that is for a different subnet than where the request originated from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the ISC-DHCPd setup as follows

```
shared-network twonetworks {
  subnet 10.0.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.240 {
    option routers 10.0.1.1;
  }

  subnet 10.0.1.32 netmask 255.255.255.240 {
    option routers 10.0.1.33;
  }
}

host {
  fixed-address 10.0.1.34;
  hardware ethernet 00:11:22:33:44:55:66;
}
```

Makes the ISC-DHCPd answer to the DHCPDISCOVER as expected:

```
dhcpd[20491]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:11:22:33:44:55:66 via 10.0.1.1
dhcpd[20491]: DHCPOFFER on 10.0.1.34 to 00:11:22:33:44:55:66 via 10.0.1.1
```